# How can we trust the authenticity of the Koran and of Muhammad?

Tags: quran, authenticity

In the early dark ages, when most of the people were illiterate and weak - and also deeply superstitious, the powerful and strong kings and warlords were able to influence them in any way they wanted.

Putting myself in Mohammed's shoes (or sandals); I could theoretically get away with declaring myself a prophet and imposing my "revelations" on all the population. I would then hire scribes to document my message from God and soon enough I'd be all powerful and memorialized for all history.

Contrast this to something like Judaism, where the revelation from God was in front of millions of people. It would be difficult for someone to start a religion from scratch and claim millions of people witnesssed it. If someone pulled that on me I'd obviously ask, "well, where are those millions of people? You should have millions of followers by now, why haven't I heard of any?". This must be why Judaism's authenticity is verified by the other major religions.

The Koran's authenticity is all based on one - otherwise obscure - person's word. Mohammed claimed God spoke to him and convinced the people around him it was true, and eventually earned a large following. But with all the violence, lack of education and forced religion of the time, how do Muslims know forsure that the Koran is really from God? (If they do).

Comment: Muhammad was a brilliant, charismatic leader. He converted his worst enemies to his cause. He built one of the most influential empires in history while he was exiled from his home town. Many people converted to Islam just from reading the Quran; if it was not the word of God, it's master poetry. With that kind of genius, I'll worship whatever God Muhammad tells me to.

Comment: the question hints at a total ignorance of islam's history. People have never been compelled to convert to islam and surviving minorities in muslim countries are a blatant proof. between the time moses received the Torah and the moment the text was canonised a time span of 9 centuries. In the islamic case it is nill. as Othman based his moshaf on a copy written by the time the prophet was alive and kept by Abu Bakr's daughter this one is the strongest of proofs there are also no different copies of Quran being discovered and the oldest copies enclose the same text al hamdulillah

Comment: @Muz "I'll worship whatever God Muhammad tells me to". Is there a typo there? God is God, Muhammad is Muhammad.

Comment: @user May be he want to write "God of Muhammad (S.A.W.)" instead of "God Muhammad". ?

Comment: Muz's statement is perfectly fine. You are just unable to comprehend its meaning. He means he will worship any GOD that the Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) tells him to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Qur'an confirmed and expanded on the previous scriptures — one of which was the Torah — and while the revelation of Moses was accompanied by a great show of miracles to large numbers of people, the same cannot really be said for later, or earlier, biblical prophets.  There have been believers since the dawn of mankind until the present day; despite his importance, Moses took up a small fraction of that timeframe.

Believers accept Muhammad and the Qur'an not because of any miracles witnessed or empirical evidence presented; all of those can be forged, especially fourteen hundred years after the fact.  Rather, we believe in them because they confirm the truth; the truth of the previous scriptures as well as the truth of right and wrong that every person is born into.  As the Qur'an says:

> There shall be no compulsion in [acceptance of] the religion. **The right course has become clear from the wrong.** So whoever disbelieves in Taghut and believes in Allah has grasped the most trustworthy handhold with no break in it. And Allah is Hearing and Knowing.
>   <sup>[[Al-Baqarah 256](http://quran.com/2/256)]</sup>

Muhammad didn't forge a new religion, he revived the same religion that has been preached since the time of Adam; the same religion that was preached to the Jews and the Christians through their own scriptures, the same religion that was even known — fragmented and distorted — to the idol-worshipping Arabs, as they themselves were descended from Abraham and Ishmael.

The same religion that was known to every descendent of Adam since time immemorial.

Comment: Interesting answer. Why then do Muslims consider themselves Muslims if their faith simply "confirms" what came before it? (I guess the same question would go for Christians too)

Comment: But you're not answering my question. I am looking for the single identifying thing that affirms Muslims belief in Islam. According to what you are saying it is simply because that is what was forced upon people at a certain time. Technically if someone wrote a "Quran 2" today, why can't he be the next prophet? What would set Muhammad apart from him? I am looking for a definitive answer, as many other faiths can offer.

Comment: Islam, when it comes to abrahamic faiths has made the community of believers universal instead of a community of kinsmen (judaism) Islamic shariah is more clement ,jewish halakha for instance kills the sinner for the fornication be them married or single, it gives no inheritance to women in the Torah etc etc. teaching humanity the right way to god almighty was done through steps and Islam is the last step and direct message from God to us earthy beings

Comment: Actually from what I've read, Judaism is very lenient. Jewish courts are castigated if they perform more than [1 execution every 70 years](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/makos/points/ma-ps-007.htm)

Comment: @Curious1 You say write 'Quran 2'? This exactly was a challenge to the Kufaar of that time as well and the challenge stands till the end of time. If ANYONE can write a single chapter similar to Quran, we will accept his claim. So no, no man can or ever will be able to produce such an infallible text.

Answer (score 6):

Several points to make here. Perhaps if you read a biography of the Prophet, some of your questions may be answered. However:

1) Character evidence: The Prophet was called 'Al Ameen' (the trustworthy) by his people much before the revelation. Even after the revelation, those who disbelieved in him never called him a liar (although they did accuse him of sorcery, magic, etc.). In addition, the many examples of the Prophet's excellent character throughout the hadith reaffirm the Prophet's character, the likes of which can never be found in history. (If you want to know about the authenticity of the hadith, that is a completely different discussion, but an important one nonetheless.)

2) The Prophet Muhammad (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) could not read or write. The revelation (in the form of Arabic verses) would come down and would surpass the skill of the best Arab poets of the day. Many of them accepted Islam. (Note - the Arabs at the time took pride in poetry and language, arguably much more than Arabs today, so the Qur'an with its beautiful, inimitable, and yet logical style was a great proof to them that it must be from God.)

3) If the Prophet desired fame or power, he would have taken it when the tribe of Quraysh offered him to be the ruler of all of Arabia, in addition to whatever in terms of wealth/women he wanted - and this was when the Prophet was in Mecca and Muslims were weak and severely persecuted.

4) In the past 1,400 years, the Qur'an has never been changed or altered in any form. In addition, there are now millions of people who have memorized the entire Qur'an worldwide - every single vowel and letter. The Qur'an itself states that God has made the Qur'an easy to memorize. (Furthermore, most of the people who have memorized it don't even know Arabic - people from India, Pakistan, Bangladesh, and other non-Arab speaking countries.) I challenge you to find any book in the world like the Qur'an. It would only make sense that the actual Word of God could have this kind of ability.

5) The scientific miracles of the Qur'an: Many scientific phenomena mentioned by the Qur'an could not have been known by any human being at the time. Sure, you could attribute it to mere lucky guessing, but to what extent? Things like life being created from water, the Big Bang theory, saltwater and freshwater not physically mixing, the sun and moon not following  one another (but each floating in an orbit), microscopic details of embryology...the list goes on. You can find more about what I'm talking about here: http://www.islamreligion.com/category/122/

There are many things I'm not listing here...an entire book can be written on the subject, and while I can't find one off the top of my head, maybe it could answer some of your questions.

Thanks!

Comment: I looked through the "scientific" examples and they are bogus. For example, the Quran said nothing revolutonary about clouds. It reflect the basic understanding at that time.

Answer (score 5):

It is not that Quran is trusted because Mohammad (PBUH) is trusted.
It is the reverse!
The main miracle of the Mohammad (PBUH) is Quran.
The prophethood of Mohammad (PBUH) is accepted
because Quran is a miracle, not vice versa.

The claim that Mohammad (PBUH) made up Quran by himself
was made even during his time, and
it is mentioned in Quran.
It is not a new claim,
according to Quran this was used also against previous prophets.
E.g. in verse 23:38 it states that
previous nations made the same claim against their prophets:

> إِنْ هُوَ إِلَّا رَجُلٌ افْتَرَىٰ عَلَى اللَّهِ كَذِبًا وَمَا نَحْنُ لَهُ بِمُؤْمِنِينَ
>
> If he is but a man who has fabricated a lie on God and we are not believers to him.

Quran clearly makes the claim in several places that
it is not the work of a man and
in fact challenges those who do not accept its authenticity
to produce something similar.
E.g. in verse 2:23 it says:

> وَإِن كُنتُمْ فِي رَيْبٍ مِّمَّا نَزَّلْنَا عَلَىٰ عَبْدِنَا فَأْتُوا بِسُورَةٍ مِّن مِّثْلِهِ وَادْعُوا شُهَدَاءَكُم مِّن دُونِ اللَّهِ إِن كُنتُمْ صَادِقِينَ * فَإِن لَّمْ تَفْعَلُوا وَلَن تَفْعَلُوا فَاتَّقُوا النَّارَ الَّتِي وَقُودُهَا النَّاسُ وَالْحِجَارَةُ ۖ أُعِدَّتْ لِلْكَافِرِينَ
>
> And if you are in doubt regarding what we have sent down to our servant
> then come up with a sura like it and
> call upon your witnesses other than God if you are honest.
> Thus if you do not, and surely you cannot,
> then be mindful of the fire whose fuel are people and stones
> [which is] promised for disbelievers.

Or in verse 17:88:

> قُل لَّئِنِ اجْتَمَعَتِ الْإِنسُ وَالْجِنُّ عَلَىٰ أَن يَأْتُوا بِمِثْلِ هَٰذَا الْقُرْآنِ لَا يَأْتُونَ بِمِثْلِهِ وَلَوْ كَانَ بَعْضُهُمْ لِبَعْضٍ ظَهِيرًا
>
> Say: even if the mankind and the genies were to gather together
> to come up with the like of this Quran,
> they would not come up with the like of it,
> even if some of them helped some other.

A lot has been written about why Quran is a miracle.
One of the main ones I think is stated in verse 28:49:

> قُلْ فَأْتُوا بِكِتَابٍ مِّنْ عِندِ اللَّهِ هُوَ أَهْدَىٰ مِنْهُمَا أَتَّبِعْهُ إِن كُنتُمْ صَادِقِينَ
>
> Say: come up with a book from God which guides better than them
> [so] I will follow it, if you are honest.

Here them refers to Quran and Torah.

Also there is a metaphor in verse 13:31 about Quran:

> وَلَوْ أَنَّ قُرْآنًا سُيِّرَتْ بِهِ الْجِبَالُ أَوْ قُطِّعَتْ بِهِ الْأَرْضُ أَوْ كُلِّمَ بِهِ الْمَوْتَىٰ ۗ بَل لِّلَّهِ الْأَمْرُ جَمِيعًا ۗ أَفَلَمْ يَيْأَسِ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا أَن لَّوْ يَشَاءُ اللَّهُ لَهَدَى النَّاسَ جَمِيعًا ۗ وَلَا يَزَالُ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا تُصِيبُهُم بِمَا صَنَعُوا قَارِعَةٌ أَوْ تَحُلُّ قَرِيبًا مِّن دَارِهِمْ حَتَّىٰ يَأْتِيَ وَعْدُ اللَّهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يُخْلِفُ الْمِيعَادَ
>
> If indeed there was a Quran that mountains were moved with it, or
> the earth were cloven asunder with it, or
> the dead were made to speak with it,
> [this is it],
> but [only] for God is the command, all of it.
> So have't those who believe become despaired that
> if God wanted he surely could guide people, all of them?
> And those who disbelieve do not cease to be struck,
> for what they have done, by calamity, or
> it will descend near their home,
> until there comes the promise of God.
> Indeed God does not break promise.

Now, since Quran is a book,
it is not a miracle restricted to a particular location or time.
It is a timeless and location-less miracle that is
presented to us.
But it is not that anyone who sees a miracle
would accept it.
You mentioned Moses (PBUH),
the Pharaoh and his people saw the miracles done by him,
but they still rejected them and called him a magician.

Answer (score 3):

To add onto what goldPseudo answered (Which was very well articulated).  The miracles of Moses (Musa), Jesus (Isa), and other prophets were witnessed by hundreds if not thousands of people during that era.  You can imagine as time went by a Father might tell his son "I saw Musa split the sea".  Fast forward hundreds of years and the story becomes "Your ancestors saw Moses split the sea".

> **[The Day] when Allah will say, "O Jesus, Son of Mary, remember My favor upon you and upon your mother when I supported you with the Pure Spirit and you spoke to the people in the cradle and in maturity; and [remember] when I taught you writing and wisdom and the Torah and the Gospel; and when you designed from clay [what was] like the form of a bird with My permission, then you breathed into it, and it became a bird with My permission; and you healed the blind and the leper with My permission; and when you brought forth the dead with My permission; and when I restrained the Children of Israel from [killing] you when you came to them with clear proofs and those who disbelieved among them said, "This is not but obvious magic."** [5:110]

*Notice how they called it **magic**.*

As amazing and grandeur as splitting the sea is or raising the dead, those who did not witness it can find it hard to believe.  For every messenger (*prophet sent with a specific book*) God sent with him a set of miracles.

> Narrated Abu Huraira that the Prophet (pbuh) said, **"Every Prophet was given miracles because of which people believed, but what I have been given is Divine Inspiration which Allah has revealed to me, so I hope my followers will outnumber the followers of other Prophets on the Day of Resurrection."** (Bukhari)

Muhammad's miracle was the Quran.  Initially the miraculous aspect was the use of the Arabic language where people were amazed at the unmatched eloquence and sophistication, where even though Muhammad was illiterate the poets of the time could not match the Quran.

> **And We did not give Muhammad, knowledge of poetry, nor is it befitting for him. It is not but a message and a clear Qur'an** [Surat Yaseen Ayah 69]

Today we discovered more miraculous aspects to the Quran, including historical, linguistic, and scientific accuracy.

The Quran is a living and ever lasting miracle so that everyone has a chance to witness it, so not a group of people at one point in time but every single person who comes across the Quran has the chance to witness this miracle and come to his own conclusion whether this is from God or made up.

> **But they say, "Why are not signs sent down to him from his Lord?" Say, "The signs are only with Allah, and I am only a clear warner."** [29:50]
>
> **And is it not sufficient for them that We revealed to you the Book which is recited to them? Indeed in that is a mercy and reminder for a people who believe.** [29:51]

Answer (score 2):

The basis of religion is faith, not reason or logic. Islam is a life choice and there is no compulsion to go into it.

Islam was spread by our noble character and the companions of the Apostle Apostles did not become a Muslim because of forced but the beauty of the character of the Prophet Muhammad SAW.

Do not force it if there are doubts about Islam, because Islam does not need the support of people who do not have confidence and dependability. And if you think that Islam is false then we, you also I both waited day evidentiary

Allah knows best .. Allahu akbar

Comment: @matzone, The Quran was another reason why Arabs became Muslims. You might want to add that too :-)

Comment: @Suhaib : Assalamu'alaikum akhi .. you're right

Answer (score 1):

For the answer of this question, we need volumes of book, and there are volumes of books. I am going to present only a small portion of my effort -

---

### Signs of Prophethood of Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ Peace be upon him)

Allah has sent, with every prophet, proofs and signs, so that people can recognize him.
Allah sent many miracles to Prophet Jesus (peace be upon him) like -  healing people, resurrecting the dead by Allah's will. 
Similarly, Allah also sent many signs to Prophet & Messenger Muhammad(pbuh), so that we can find him.

I can categorize them in 4 categories. Let me just add some examples with no details (for keeping it short).

> **1. Quran is a miraculous revelation**

- Quran is a literal word of God, preserved to its letters till today for 1400 years. No other revealed book is preserve this way. Fulfillment of God's own word in the Quran - "(15:9) Indeed, it is We who sent down the Quran and indeed, We will preserve it."  http://www.myquranstudy.com/Study.aspx?15:9
- Has Literary miracles
- Has Scientific miracles
- Has Historical miracles
- Has Mathematical miracles
- And more…

> **2. Other Miracles given to Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ phuh) - all by the will of God**

- Muhammad (phuh) broke the moon in two pieces and joined back, by Allah's permission
- Muhammad (phuh) went from Makkah to Jerusalem and then to Heaven, and back to Makkah in one night
- He (phuh) healed people by mere supplication to God,
- He (phuh) fed thousands of people with little food,
- He (phuh) caused rain and stopped rain by his dua to Allah, when people requested of him
- And more…

Please read some of the Miracles here: http://www.myquranstudy.com/Articles/

All the above miracles were seen and reported by many people and some were seen by thousands of people (Muslims and non-Muslims alike).

> **3. Muhammad (phuh) Foretold Many Events - by Allah's will**

Past fulfilled prophecies by Muhammad (phuh):

- Fall of Persian empire in the hands of Muslims (who were few and had no military training)
- Martyrdom of Umar, Uthman (2nd and 3rd Khalifa)
- Prophecy about many of his companions
- Foretelling 30 years of righteous Caliphate.
- And many more

End-time prophecies by Muhammad (phuh):

- Foretelling that Arabs will build tall buildings (look at Dubai now)
- Foretelling of rampant usury (Bank interest)
  (note: usury is major sin in Islamic law)
- Foretelling of widespread shamelessness (half naked women, adult films etc.)
- Foretelling of sad state of the Muslim (as we see now) due to love of duniya (this life)
- And many more...

> **4. Muhammad's (phuh) Coming was foretold in other books**

- His coming was foretold in the Purans (Hindu Scriptures)
- His coming was foretold in the Vedas (Hindu Scriptures)
- His coming was foretold in the Bible

Don’t believe in God? Don’t worry you will start to believe if the right religion comes to you, insha’Allah. It happened to many people!

---

**Further readings:**

- https://www.kalamullah.com/Books/The%20Messengers%20and%20the%20Messages.pdf

**Biography of Prophet Muhammad(pbuh):**

- Book: https://www.missionislam.com/knowledge/books/Ar-Raheeq_Al-Makhtum.pdf
- Videos by Yasir Qadhi (about 100 videos):    https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAEA99D24CA2F9A8F

And above all these, the beauty and justice of Sharia is beyond compare.

Women's right, kindness to animals and nature, directives of family-bond, fairness in business, call for purification of hearts and more - there is beauty in all these in Islam, for those who see!

```
Do you still deny the Prophethood of Muhammad(ﷺ)?
```

Answer (score -1):

there is plenty of evidence. I'll show you some.

Noble Quran 53:49:

"That He is the Lord of Sirius (the Mighty Star);"

Noble Quran 81:15-16 :

"So verily I call to witness the planets - that recede

Go straight, or hide;"

It sounds as if these verses(81:15-16) are talking about orbits.

Noble Quran 37:6-7 :

"We have indeed decked the lower heaven with beauty (in) the stars,-

and for guard against all obstinate rebellious evil spirits,"

Check this out Astronomy http://www.islamicity.com/mosque/TOPICQ/A.htm.

You'll find evidence.

Answer (score -1):

If you think, a man living in desert, never went to school or college, can give scientific fact 1400 years ago, which are invented only in 19th Century and 100% correct data? It's only the God who know at that time.

In any religion these facts are not available. Some of those are:

**Botany: Gender in plants**

> Verse (36:36): Exalted is He who created all pairs - from what the
> earth grows and from themselves and from that which they do not know.

**Embryology:**

> Verse (22:5) O People, if you should be in doubt about the Resurrection, then [consider that] indeed, We created you from dust, then from a sperm-drop, then from a clinging clot, and then from a lump of flesh, formed and unformed - that We may show you. And We settle in the wombs whom We will for a specified term, then We bring you out as a child, and then [We develop you] that you may reach your [time of] maturity. And among you is he who is taken in [early] death, and among you is he who is returned to the most decrepit [old] age so that he knows, after [once having] knowledge, nothing. And you see the earth barren, but when We send down upon it rain, it quivers and swells and grows [something] of every beautiful kind.

**Astronomy:**

> Verse (36:39) And the moon - We have determined for it phases, until it returns [appearing] like the old date stalk.
>
> Verse (36:40) It is not permitted to the Sun to catch up the Moon, nor can the Night outstrip the Day: Each (just) swims along in (its own) orbit.
>
> Verse (21:33) (God is) the one Who created the night, the day, the sun and the moon. Each one is travelling in an orbit with its own motion.
>
> Verse (51:47) And the heaven We constructed with strength, and indeed, We are [its] expander.

There are more than 1000 such scientific facts.