# Proof of Koran Authenticity

Tags: quran, scientific-proof

While much of religion is faith, are there any statements in the Koran we can point to that prove its authenticity?

Using the Torah as an example, one of the things Jews point to is the fact that the Torah says there is only one animal that has split hooves but doesn't chew its cud (the pig). Only God can make that statement since nobody else could be sure enough, and if proven wrong, the religion would fall apart.

What can we say about the Koran that accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: I don't know about Jews, but as a Christian, I can say that if we were to discover some other animal with split hooves that doesn't chew it's cud, it would not cause Judaism nor Christianity to "fall apart." Using that litmus test, the Torah and other parts of the Jewish and Christian scriptures would already have fallen apart centuries ago. Most modern scholars hold a view that when such scripture was written, it was done from the understanding of the culture writing it (with obvious exceptions for divine intervention).

Comment: If you want an example from Jewish scripture of its divine inspiration, the most obvious place to look (from the perspective of Christians, anyway) is the book of Isaiah, which foretells the coming of the Messiah.

Comment: @Flimzy Can you give an example of something in the Torah that has been proven false that would cause it to fall apart by the litmus test I suggested?

Comment: I think you missed my point. I don't think the Torah ever can "fall apart," so no, I can't prove that it would fall apart.  My point is that split hooves isn't a very interesting test.  I can't prove my highschool math text is wrong either--but that doesn't make it special.  Judging a religious text by its scientific accuracy is silly.  Judge it by its religious accuracy.  The Torah does talk about the earth being flat--but that doesn't prove it's wrong, it just proves it's written in poetic language.

Comment: @Flimzy "Judging a religious text by its scientific accuracy is silly. Judge it by its religious accuracy." I have no idea what "religious accuracy" is supposed to mean, can you explain?

Comment: duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8079/how-can-we-trust-the-authenticity-of-the-koran-and-of-muhammad

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too broad".  The current answers attempt to answer the first question, but the OP seems to want answers to the second question.  See 
[Why we should avoid asking multi-question questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions)

Answer (score 0):

Quran says in [chapter 2, verse 23-24](http://quran.com/2/23-24)

> And if you are in doubt about what We have sent down upon Our Servant [Muhammad], then produce a surah the like thereof and call upon your witnesses other than Allah , if you should be truthful. But if you do not - and you will never be able to - then fear the Fire, whose fuel is men and stones, prepared for the disbelievers.

and in [chapter 4, version 82](http://quran.com/4/82)

> Then do they not reflect upon the Qur'an? If it had been from [any] other than Allah , they would have found within it much contradiction.

Comment: I am not sure what you are getting at

Comment: @Curious1, it s pretty self defining, even then, thi may help, the phrase 
"what We have sent down upon Our Servant [Muhammad]" refers to Quran.
so in even simpler words, it's a challenge to the non-believers to create a single Surah (chapter) which is equivalent and good enough as the Surah's of Quran.

Answer (score 0):

Allah's promise in the Qur'an:

> ```
>  “Indeed, it is We who sent down the Qur'an and indeed, We will
> be its guardian.” (Q.15:9). 
>
> “Then do they not reflect upon the Qur'an? If it had been from [any]
> other than Allah , they would have found within it much
> contradiction.“ (Q. 4:82)
>
> “Say, "What thing is greatest in testimony?" Say, " Allah is witness
> between me and you. And this Qur'an was revealed to me that I may warn
> you thereby and whomever it reaches. Do you [truly] testify that with
> Allah there are other deities?" Say, "I will not testify [with you]."
> Say, "Indeed, He is but one God, and indeed, I am free of what you
> associate [with Him]."“ (Q. 6:19)
>
> “And this is a Book which We have sent down, blessed and confirming
> what was before it, that you may warn the Mother of Cities and those
> around it. Those who believe in the Hereafter believe in it, and they
> are maintaining their prayers.“ (Q. 6:92)
>
> “And indeed, [O Muhammad], you receive the Qur'an from one Wise and
> Knowing.“  (Q. 27:6)
>
> The revelation of the Book is from Allah , the Exalted in Might, the
> Wise. (Q. 45:2)
> ```

The Qur'an has been preserved in both oral and written form in a way no other book has, and with each form providing a check and balance for the authenticity of the other.

if you need some `human explanation`, you can find it at [this link](http://www.freewebs.com/proofofislam/authenticityofquran.htm) and [this](http://www.ilaam.net/Articles/AuthenticQuran.html)

---

**EDIT**

---

Based on comments of OP, I'd like to add it to my answer because I realized that it related.

OP said, *"You're simple quoting some text written by and about one man. I could have written the same thing."*
I just simple quoting because he has same arguments for Quran tafseer. I wouldn't write it again. Just simply linked to it.

OP said, *"Additionally, your assertion that no other book has been preserved like the Qura'an is false. Prime example being the Torah, off of which the Qura'an is based. (as verified by discoveries like the Dead Sea Scrolls)"* 
About Torah, I realized and believed that it exist. If you are Muslim, you will find different how Quran preserved and Torah (generally, [people of book](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/what-book-is-referred-to-in-the-phrase-people-of-the-book)) preserved. I'd like to add verse Q. 3:78 about it.

> ```
>  And indeed, there is among them a party who alter the Scripture
> with their tongues so you may think it is from the Scripture, but it
> is not from the Scripture. And they say, "This is from Allah ," but it
> is not from Allah . And they speak untruth about Allah while they
> know. (Q. 3:78)
> ```

Comment: You're simple quoting some text written by and about one man. I could have written the same thing.

Comment: Additionally, your assertion that no other book has been preserved like the Qura'an is false. Prime example being the Torah, off of which the Qura'an is based. (as verified by discoveries like the Dead Sea Scrolls)

Comment: thanks for your comment, you can looked up at my **EDIT** label.

Comment: @Curious1 There is only one version of Quran. Do you claim there is only one version of Torah? Not recognized version, but just version.

Comment: @mezhang multiple variations of the Quran have been found. The Dead Sea scrolls have been dated at nearly 2000 years old and are identical to the current Torah. It seems likely everything has been the same all along for the Jews.

Comment: @Curious1  `Dead Sea scrolls` that is interesting i will definitely try to make a research on it. Thanks :)

Comment: @suhail I'm surprised you've never heard of it. They've been exhibited at museums around the world and examined by nearly all leading archaeologists in the area.

Comment: @AhmadAzwarAnas your answer is Islamically correct but *only* Islamacically. The quoted verses do not prove anything if you are not a Muslim :)

Comment: @Curious1 Do the scrolls have the Torah in it's entirety?
The variations you might be talking about are only difference of  script in different regions which doesn't qualify as versions...

Answer (score -3):

I believed in Holy Qur'an by it's scientific miracles.

Update: This is in need of one's own research, which quite depends on the person's science background, and surely God the Compassionate the Merciful will help in this path. This is a broad concept with broad detail and discussion, and not something that one could get the essential parts from it without the details. Maybe even better not to be provided incompletely. So I'm not pointing to this site as a reference, I'm providing it as an example, and even not an example to base the whole issue upon. Just to show you how an example could be.

You can find a description of some of them here: [The Scientific Miracles in the Holy Quran](http://www.islam-guide.com/)

Comment: I wrote an update to resolve the misunderstanding. To describe it even further, I have been working for quite a few hours on another question which is related to just "one" scientific miracle, trying to provide a yet "brief" answer that does not get denied just because of the incomplete reasoning provided in support of it. I will post it soon if God wants, and then I will put the link to it here as a reference to what I'm talking about.