# What evidence is there in the Quran that it is the word of God?

Tags: quran, scientific-proof

I know us Muslims claim that Islam is the true religion, however, if we were to show a non-Muslim proof of our belief, what proof would we be able to show them?

I would appreciate quotes from Quran and Ahadith

Thanks in advance

Comment: See also: "[Why was Quran sent down?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23904/9123)" & "[What is the proof that Islam is THE truth? How can I have 100% certainty?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24463/9123)"

Comment: http://quran.com/14/4-12

Comment: duplicate of https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8079/how-can-we-trust-the-authenticity-of-the-koran-and-of-muhammad and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8681/proof-of-koran-authenticity .

Answer (score 1):

You want proof from the Quran and Sunnah that the Quran is the truth? There is nothing scientific about that. The only proof exists only in the Quran. Allah says:

[image]

> Indeed, it is We who sent down the Qur'an and indeed, We will be its guardian.

If you are looking for Quranic verses that could vaguely describe things science has established (in no way it is a scientific proof) you can visit the following website:

http://www.quranandscience.com/

It has what you need. Also as provided in the comment, Religion can not be proven by science, it is faith based @ [What is the proof that Islam is THE truth? How can I have 100% certainty?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24463/9123)

Comment: i do not agree with this site's interpretation of 7 earths (as layers of planet earth).

Comment: what i think about 7 earths: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/20280/difference-between-7-skies-and-position-of-the-heavens#comment45581_23666

Answer (score 0):

http://quran.com/51/47 :

> And the heaven We constructed with strength, and indeed, We are [its]
>   expander.

— i think, and many other people think, this is about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space

http://quran.com/18/86 :

> Until, when he reached the setting of the sun, he found it [as if]
>   setting in a spring of dark mud, and he found near it a people. Allah
>   said, "O Dhul-Qarnayn, either you punish [them] or else adopt among
>   them [a way of] goodness."

— i think, i have found this interpretation by myself, this is about falling of the sun into black hole

and i have found acceptable interpretations for several places of quran which or which translation look unscientifical.

Answer (score 0):

If you want prove such a thing for non-muslim people, you have to prove Islam for him first.

There is no scientific or philosophical reasons for Quran, and I think this is wrong to try proving that with scientific facts and sticking them to Quran, because this can make misunderstanding about that.

Comment: I'll be happy to know the reason of the down-vote.

Answer (score -2):

Earth is described as egg-shaped (not a perfect circular globe), a fact which was discovered recently in the human history.
[enter link description here](http://www.aljazeerah.info/Islamic%20Editorials/2007/September/The%20Scientific%20Evidence%20That%20God%20Exists%20and%20the%20Holy%20Qur'an%20Is%20His%20Message%20to%20Humanity%20By%20Hassan%20Ali%20El-Najjar.htm)
**In Chapter 79, Verse 30, the Holy Quran mentions that:**

**And the Earth, after that, He made it egg-shaped**.

Comment: Why downvote? I think, this is a good point.

Comment: While the Earth is not perfectly spherical, it's an [oblate spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spheroid), i.e., it's [flattened at the poles and bulges at the equator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_the_Earth).

Answer (score -3):

We now talk about pass words in our smart phones. They contain secret codes known only to the person owning the phone. Then I came to discover that Muhammad could not have written a book in which he put words he did not understand himself, the abbreviations like Aleef Laam Miim; Haa Miim; Qaaf Haa Yaa ,Ain Saad, etc. What is amazing is that almost all the chapters that begin with the secret codes talk first about the Qur-an. So I realized that God has put his pass words as a strong proof that the Qur-an is not a man's creation. The words to me are divine rubber stamps, divine codes, which even Muhammad could not understand. But he read the secret words and let his writers write them as they are not his own words. These would be a challenge to him for speaking words he himself did not understand.

Comment: Try adding references